# How Can I reference pervious row in a mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql, mamp

Firstly I'm a sql rookie and only know the basics. I have tried googling ( and have seen some references and example of similar but I was not able to follow or apply to my problem), I'm not even 100% if it is possible in my situation. I'm trying figure out how to perform a select that involves calculating a column based on a column from the pervious row. I want the balance from the pervious to be the carry in the next:

I have a list of transactions

```
 _____________________________________________
| id |   Date    |  time |  amount |  type    |
|  1 |2014-01-01 | 12:00 |   2000  |  payin   |
|  5 |2014-01-01 | 17:00 |    -20  |  payout  |
|  2 |2014-01-01 | 18:00 |    -20  |  payout  |
|  3 |2014-01-02 | 12:00 |    -10  |  payout  |
|  4 |2014-01-03 | 12:00 |   +300  |  payin   |
```

As you can see there is an id ( which is the primary key ) but its order is not guaranteed because a transaction could be back dated and added after more recent transactions have been. I would like to get the following but I am completely lost. SQL is not my area at all.

```
|   Date    |  time |  carry  |   amount | balance  |  type   |
|2014-01-01 | 12:00 |       0 |    2000  |     2000 |  payin  |
|2014-01-01 | 17:00 |    2000 |     -20  |     1980 |  payout |
|2014-01-01 | 17:00 |    1980 |     -20  |     1960 |  payout |
|2014-01-02 | 12:00 |    1960 |     -10  |     1950 |  payout |
|2014-01-03 | 12:00 |    1950 |      -1  |     1949 |  payout |
|2014-01-03 | 12:00 |    1949 |      -5  |     1944 |  payout |
|2014-01-03 | 12:00 |    1944 |    +300  |     2244 |  payin  |
```

and in turn I believe I can get the following by summing based on type and group by date

```
|   Date    |  carry  | total in | total out | balance | 
|2014-01-01 |       0 |    2000  |      -40  |   1960  | 
|2014-01-02 |    1960 |       0  |      -10  |    1950 | 
|2014-01-03 |    1950 |     300  |       -6  |    2244 |
```

up till now I have been getting the desired result by querying the mysql data base from Nodejs for each date specific date using the following queries ( all performed separately ):

```
var sql_init_Balance_day ='select sum(amount) as total '+
                        'from transactions '+
                        'Where transaction_date<\''+mdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'\'';

var sql_closing_Balance_day ='select sum(amount) as closingBalance '+
                        'from transactions '+
                        'Where transaction_date<\''+mtomorrow.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'\'';

var sql_payins_day = 'select sum(amount) as deposits '+
                        'from transactions '+
                        'Where transaction_date=\''+mdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'\''+
                        ' and type=\'payin\'';

var sql_payouts_day = 'select sum(amount) as deductions '+
                        'from transactions '+
                        'Where transaction_date=\''+mdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'\' '+
                        'and type=\'payout\'';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the carry using variables

```
select `Date`, max(case when rowNum = 1 then carry end) carry,
    sum(case when type = 'payin' then amount else 0 end) total_in,
    sum(case when type = 'payout' then amount else 0 end) total_out,
    sum(amount) balance
from (
    select `Date`, time, @balance carry, amount,
    (@balance := @balance + amount) balance, type,
    @rowNum := IF(`Date` = @prevDate, @rowNum + 1, 1) rowNum,
    @prevDate := `Date`
    from transactions 
    cross join (select @balance := 0) t1
    order by `Date`, time
) t1 group by `Date`
```

**Update:** Another query using a self join. Self joins are typically slower than using variables but it might be good enough for what you need.

```
select t1.date
    coalesce(@prevBalance,0) carry,
    sum(case when t2.type = 'payin' and t2.date = t1.date then t2.amount else 0 end) total_in,
    sum(case when t2.type = 'payout' and t2.date = t1.date then t2.amount else 0 end) total_out,
    sum(t2.amount) balance,
    @prevBalance := sum(t2.amount)
from transactions t1
join transactions t2 on t2.date <= t1.date
group by t1.date
order by t1.date
```

Comment: I like your solution but it has few issues, one the balance for each row was only the difference between the payins and payouts this I was able to adjust by adding the `@balance` to the `sum(amount)` but unfortunitly the 1st row carry should be 0, how might I include this case?

Comment: @jonnieM can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem? from what i can tell the 1st carry will be 0 but there's probably something i'm missing

Comment: sorry for the delay here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7155/1) although here it appears to select 0 from the first row for the carry, but not on my local MAMP

Comment: I was able to get the desired result by removing the max from the outer query and just using carry..`select transaction_date, transaction_time, carry, sum(amount),
sum(case when type = 'payin' then amount else 0 end) total_in,
    sum(case when type = 'payout' then amount else 0 end) total_out,
    balance 
from ( **YOUR SUBQUERY** ) tt group by transaction_date`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get your first result with the following:

```
SELECT date, 
       time, 
       @carry := COALESCE(@carry,0) carry,
       amount,
       @carry := @carry + amount balance, 
       type
  FROM transaction
ORDER BY date, time
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12db1/5)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an aggregation query for everything except closing balance:

```
select transaction_date,
       sum(amount) as total,
       substring_index(group_concat(closing_balance order by time desc), ',', 1) as ClosingBalance,
       sum(case when type = 'payin' then amount else 0 end) as deposits,
       sum(case when type = 'payout' then amount else 0 end) as deductions
from transactions
group by transaction_date;
```

The logic for closing balance uses a trick to get the last balance on the day.

Answer (score -1):

You could read your records into an array and then sort them by date and time and manually sum them.  a lot of work to set up, but it woud get the job done.

```
    while ($T_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] =  array('TC_Group'=>$TC_Group,'uname'=>$uname);
    }   
    asort($data);
   // process data
```

Comment: I was specifically asking about sql. I can do all this in node ( or php) but thats not helpful if I need to move platform.